# Something Wrong with the start menu on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, start-menu

Whenever I start a maximized window of Google Chrome, my start menu disappears for some reason. The problem isn't just with Chrome. Although it is visible on both Internet Explorer 9 and Opera, the browsers render things *under* the start menu, so the elements at the bottom aren't visible. Similar problems are occurring in other applications. What's wrong?

Comment: Before you ask, I _didn't_ accidentally turn on the `autohide taskbar` feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this app](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/54842-taskbar-always-top-disable-enable.html) to make the Taskbar to be on top always.